# How to set the new margin on the next page?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry

I have a large footer that needs to be placed on the first page of a document. To make it fit, I've used the geometry package and increased the bottom margin.

For the header/footer manipulation, I'm using `fancyhdr`. How do I use `\newgeometry{bottom=2cm}` again on the `2nd` page of the text, without using `\newpage` and guessing where in the text the second page starts?

Can LaTex execute commands on next page? Something like

`\NextPageExecute{\newgeometry{bottom=3cm}}`

would solve the problem. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

% Header customization, get the reference to the last page. 
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Header customization, get the reference to the last page. 
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}
% Fancy pagestyle for the rest of the document.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My form 11/17}
\rhead{Page \thepage of \pageref{LastPage}}
% Remove the horizontal line from the header.
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% Remove everything from the footline.
\cfoot{}

\definecolor{CUSTOM}{HTML}{00529e}

% Set the header and footer style. 
\fancypagestyle{empty}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \lhead{My form 11/17}
  \rhead{Page \thepage of \pageref{LastPage}}
  \lfoot{
    Something something. \\
    Memo text. \\ 
    Some address information. \\
    Telephone numbers. \\
  }
  \rfoot{
    \textcolor{CUSTOM}{\Huge{HUGE TEXT}}
  }
}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}.
```

The first page looks like this:

[image]

And the second page has this unnecessarily large footer space:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `afterpage` package does exactly what you are looking for. Seen as you only want the `3cm` bottom margin on the first page and (for example) `2cm` elsewhere, I would recommend having the default layout with `2cm` and using `\newgeometry` on the first page only (followed by a `\restoregeometry\clearpage` in `\afterpage`):

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}% 2cm bottom (usual)

% Header customization, get the reference to the last page. 
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Header customization, get the reference to the last page. 
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}
% Fancy pagestyle for the rest of the document.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My form 11/17}
\rhead{Page \thepage of \pageref{LastPage}}
% Remove the horizontal line from the header.
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% Remove everything from the footline.
\cfoot{}

\definecolor{CUSTOM}{HTML}{00529e}

% Set the header and footer style. 
\fancypagestyle{empty}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \lhead{My form 11/17}
  \rhead{Page \thepage of \pageref{LastPage}}
  \lfoot{
    Something something. \\
    Memo text. \\ 
    Some address information. \\
    Telephone numbers. \\
  }
  \rfoot{
    \textcolor{CUSTOM}{\Huge{HUGE TEXT}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm} % Change to 3cm bottom (temp)
\thispagestyle{empty}
\afterpage{\restoregeometry\clearpage}
% CONTENT HERE

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image: page1]

Page 2:

[image: page2]